# Failed to start avahi mDNS/DNS-SD stack

Tags: openldap

I have configured openldap manually on opensuse 42.3  and it's working fine until i didn't configure LDAP and Kerberos Client. after i configure use a directory as identity provider and checked(BEFORE REBOOT) getent passwd. i was able to see the users and able to login.After reboot the system the below error is coming:

```
[FAILED] Failed to start Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD stack
see systemctl status avahi-daemon.service for detials

[FAILED] Failed to start wicked AutoIPv4 supplicant service
see systemctl status wickedd-auto4.service for details

[FAILED] Failed to start wicked DHCPv6 supplicant service
see systemctl status wickedd DHCPv6 supplicant service for details

[FAILED] Failed to start wicked DHCPV4 supplicant service
see systemctl status wickedd-dhcp4.service for details
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for my question?

we have to enter bind_policy soft in vim /etc/ldap.conf file. so you don't get an error further

Comment: if you joined you system into domain using ldap with kerberos client then use the bind_policy soft in vim /etc/ldap.conf